# How to determine exponential decay rate of sum of sines function when the time constant is different for each exponential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I will show you my MATLAB code:

```
t = 0:0.1:10*pi;
test_sine = exp(-0.1*t).*sin(t) + exp(-0.2*t).*sin(2*t);
```

The time constant for each of my sine waves are different, but I would like to know how I would go about determining what the decay rate is for my test_sine function.

Comment: You can write it as $e^{-.1t}\sin(t)(1+\epsilon(t))$, where $\epsilon(t)$ is a term that goes to zero (exponentially) fast, so the decay rate will be dominated by the first term - in other words, the slowest-decreasing.

Comment: @JJacquelin The time constant for the first sine is -0.1, and the second sine is -0.2. How do I find what the decay rate is of test_sine? Does that provide clarification?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The first term will always be the slowest to decay?

Comment: the one with the largest value on the exponent; in this case, since $-.1 \gt -.2$, then the term with $e^{-.1t}$ dominates.